# Django model with only permissions defined breaks tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, permissions, models

I'm using a meta class in my application model to define application level permissions, there are no actual fields defined. This works as expected, but when I try to run my tests I get django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: xxx_xxx. Is there a way to exclude a model when running unit tests?

```
class feeds(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("change_feed_defaults", "change_feed_defaults"),
            ("view_logs", "view_logs"),
            ("preview_tagger", "preview_tagger"),
            ("preview_url", "preview_url"),
            ("view_feeds", "view_feeds"),
            ("text_tag_feedback", "text_tag_feedback"),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provided the full stack trace, I can only guess what's going on.

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: yourapp_yourmodel.` is a common
error that arise your database does not reflect your models.

If you're using `django>=1.7`, maybe you just to create the corresponding migration files with a `python manage.py makemigrations yourapp`.
You'll probably want to read [the documentation section that explains migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/). It's a really useful tool too manage your database state (adding models, fields, etc.), but it's sometimes tricky to get the whole picture.

Comment: Glad it helps :) If it solved your issue, can you consider marking my answer as correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this same thing.. with a fake model to hold extra permissions.. and I had other issues.. not the same as yours.. but problems.. so I decided to take the bull by the horns and write a bit of code to explicitly create my extra permissions, and I put that code in my library:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

def get_or_create_permission(codename, name, content_type):
    permission = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, codename=codename).first()

    if not permission:
        permission =  Permission.objects.create(content_type=content_type, codename=codename, name=name)
        print "Created Permission: %s in content type: %s" % (permission, content_type,)
    else:
        print "Found Permission: %s in ContentType: %s" % (permission, content_type,)

    return permission

def get_or_create_content_type(app_label, name, model):
      content_type = ContentType.objects.filter(app_label=app_label, model=model).first()
    if not content_type:
        content_type = ContentType.objects.create(app_label=app_label, model=model, name=name)
        print "Created ContentType: %s" % content_type
    else:
        print "Found ContentType: %s" % content_type

    return content_type
```

Ok now in your urls.py (or anywhere else it will be executed on startup):

```
content_type = get_or_create_content_type('appname', 'Feeds', 'feeds')
get_or_create_permission('change_feed_defaults', 'Change Feed Defaults', content_type)
get_or_create_permission('view_logs', 'View Logs', content_type)
# etc
```

This assures that your permissions are there upon startup.  One of these days I will make a wrapper for this so that I only have to pass a dictionary of permissions and it'll do everything in one function call...